# vim, create new line after or before selected line

Tags: vim

In vim I can jump to line number, for example, 14 like this : "14gg"; Then I can use "o" or "O" to create a new line after or before this line.
Is there a way to create a new line before or after 14th without jumping to it? Something like "14O" or "14o" (these commands don't work)

Comment: Since the cursor moves to the newly created line. I see no difference between `14ggO` and this new command you are looking for. Why is a new mapping for `14ggO` not sufficient for you?

Comment: You could do `14ggo<Esc><C-O>`  to jump back to where you were (and then you could map some key to it).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, answer of Mohit Chandak is what I was looking for

Comment: Glad that I could help because I have same laziness syndrome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a mapping in your .vimrc file for this, to map a single character to what you want to achieve. (Create a .vimrc in your home directory if you dont have one already i.e /home/user)

For example, put following lines in your .vimrc file

```
map e ggo
map E ggO
```

Now whenever you will do something like 14e, it will go to line 14 and insert a new line below and take you in insert mode. Likewise, E for inserting line above

Please note that this may override whatever functionality key e and E might have in vim.

I strongly recommend simply using 14ggo in a go to achieve what you want

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a duplicate of this superuser question: https://superuser.com/questions/147715/vim-insert-empty-line-above-current-line-not-open-i-e-without-entering-inser

`append()` is the standard answer to your question:

```
:call append(14, '')
```

The cursor will not get moved, nor the position marks.

Comment: Not a duplicate. And as I see I wasn't fully clear; I do need to jump to new line, just dont want to press additional gg or G. Answer of Mohit Chandak is what i need

Comment: Oh. My mistake then. I understood that you did not want to move the cursor. ^^'

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
14Go<Esc>
14GO<Esc>
```

or:

```
:14norm o
:14norm O
```

or:

```
:14put=
:14put!=
```

You'll need to jump back to where you come from anyway.